# Updating another Widget also when current widget is updated

Tags: java, android, widget

Hello everyone I am facing a problem
I am using two widgets here
The widget at top is of size 4*2 and bottom one is of 4*1
So when i click on toggle of upper widget it changes the toggle state from on to off n viceverse
This same implements in case of 2nd one also

I want that both the widgets must update simultaneously
Any help will be appericiated!!!

this [code](http://paste.ofcode.org/Qt8paHmQ4USKyBXi84jpds) is for upper widget i.e of size 4*2 i.e at top
I have used the same code for 2nd widget also just there I changed the name of class to WidgetProvider1.class

**The image is:**

[image]

Comment: this [code](http://paste.ofcode.org/gG5rcTYuBYkXGGtk7K28FB) is for upper widget i.e of size 4*1 i.e at bottom

Answer (score 0):

You updated your widgets by id, but you can pass [array](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/appwidget/AppWidgetManager.html#updateAppWidget%28int[],%20android.widget.RemoteViews%29) of your ids or just update [all](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/appwidget/AppWidgetManager.html#updateAppWidget%28android.content.ComponentName,%20android.widget.RemoteViews%29) widgets.

**EDITED**

For example, replace

```
AppWidgetManager wm = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context);
wm.updateAppWidget(widgetId, views);
```

with

```
AppWidgetManager wm = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context);
ComponentName cn = new ComponentName(context, WidgetProvider.class);
wm.updateAppWidget(cn, views);
```

Comment: actually I am working over the project that is left by someone and I am not having any prior experience with widgets, but from studying regarding this, I come to know that widget is getting updated from this
appWidgetManager.notifyAppWidgetViewDataChanged(
      appWidgetIds[i], R.id.listViewWidget);

can you tell what steps I must follow to achieve this
how can I update all widgets?